# Find Tab Characters in emacs

Tags: emacs

How do I find a tab character in emacs?

Comment: This also answers the question of: how to I type a literal tab character in emacs: just hit C-q then <TAB> key. Voila!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
C-s C-q <TAB>
```

C-s starts an incremental search, and then C-q runs quoted-insert, which inserts the next character you type literally.  Then, pressing the TAB key will insert a tab character.  Continue hitting C-s to go to the next tab character.

Comment: Thanks.  Emacs newbies asking this question will want to know that <TAB> means "hit the tab key".

Answer (score 25):

Just do the combination of keys as follows:

```
C-s TAB
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I just tested this in various modes in Windows emacs v22.3.1  and linux v 23.0.92.1

You don't need the C-q

Comment: I'm speculating (and didn't downvote), but maybe because people didn't think it would work, or that they figured that if chernevik were having problems, then the unquoted TAB wasn't working for him?

Comment: All of C-s TAB, C-s C-q TAB, and C-s C-q C-i work for me. Maybe somebody could explain when/why C-s TAB doesn't work?

Comment: Downvotes may also happen because it only answers the specific problem, without helping the asker with the general understanding of what <TAB> does differently in search mode and typing mode. (It works for me, even though I would have suspected it not to.)

Answer (score 9):

I use [whitespace mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) to highlight all tabs with the following in my .emacs file:

```
;whitespace http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace 
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style '(tabs tab-mark)) ;turns on white space mode only for tabs
(global-whitespace-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

Hit `C-s` to start an incremental search, then type `C-q C-i` to search for a literal tab character.

If you want to visualize tab characters, you can add the following to your `~/.emacs` file to colorize tabs:

```
; Draw tabs with the same color as trailing whitespace
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (font-lock-add-keywords
       nil
        '(("\t" 0 'trailing-whitespace prepend))
     )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In some versions of emacs, you can simply do

```
C-s <TAB>
```

where `<TAB>` is a stroke of the tab key.

If that doesn't work, `C-i` is a synonym for `<TAB>`, so to search for tabs, do

```
C-s C-i
```

In addition, `C-q <TAB>` means the same thing as `C-i`, so you could also search for tabs with

```
C-s C-q <TAB>
```

Furthermore, `C-i` or `C-q <TAB>` can be used to insert a tab character in other situations where the tab key does not. For example, if you have emacs set to [auto-expand tabs into spaces](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Indent-Tabs-Mode.html), you can still use `C-i` to insert the tab character while editing.